# Josephus Problem - A faster Solution

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, algorithm-design

I came through Josephus problem a little while ago. Problem is stated as follows :

> "People are standing in a circle waiting to be executed. Counting begins at a specified point in the circle and proceeds around the circle in a specified direction. After a specified number of people are skipped, the next person is executed. The procedure is repeated with the remaining people, starting with the next person, going in the same direction and skipping the same number of people, until only one person remains, and is freed.
> The problem — given the number of people, starting point, direction, and number to be skipped — is to choose the position in the initial circle to avoid execution."

*Though I was able to figure out O(n) (n being no. of people & k being specified no of people skipped) solution to this problem using DP.I came to know that a better solution for larger value of n exists O(k*log(n)),but unable to figure it out.*

Please help me with O(k*log(n)) solution.

Comment: Better solution than? Where is your question?  
After citing Josephus problem you have acknowledged the existence of $O(n)$ and $O(k\log(n))$ solutions. Good, well done.

Comment: I am looking for k*log(n) solution.

Comment: I understand that you need help with this solution. Do you have it? What is unclear? What do you expect?

Comment: I have checked the magic keyphrase `josephus klogn` and to my surprise, there is [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845260/josephus-for-large-n-facebook-hacker-cup!) answer to it but there was more, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/12qicm/1162012_challenge_111_difficult_the_josephus/) are implementations in several languages (even XSLT). But this might not have been the problem since probably you have seen some (pseudo)code. According to SO, the part where n%k is subtracted is problematic, but you have not asked a question...

Comment: What are $n$ and $k$? The running-time bound smells like "solve on paper, compute the result according to the formula you get".

Answer (score 1):

You can find both the $O(n)$ and $O(k.log(n))$ solutions and time complexity analysis [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/others/josephus_problem.html)

Here is the $O(k.log(n))$ algorithm:

> For relatively small $k$ we can come up with a better solution than the
> above recursive solution in $O(n)$. If $k$ is a lot smaller than $n$, then
> we can delete multiple numbers $(⌊\frac nk⌋)$ in one run without looping over.
> Afterwards we have $n−⌊\frac nk⌋$ numbers left, and we start with the
> $(⌊\frac nk⌋⋅n)$-th number. So we have to shift by that many. We can notice
> that $⌊\frac nk⌋⋅n$ is simply $n (mod \space k)$. And since we removed every $k$-th number,
> we have to add the number of numbers that we removed before the result
> index.
>
> Also, we need to handle the case when $n$ becomes less than $k$. In this
> case, the above optimization would cause an infinite loop.

```c++
int josephus(int n, int k) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    if (k == 1)
        return n-1;
    if (k > n)
        return (josephus(n-1, k) + k) % n;
    int cnt = n / k;
    int res = josephus(n - cnt, k);
    res -= n % k;
    if (res < 0)
        res += n;
    else
        res += res / (k - 1);
    return res;
}
```

And here is the time complexity analysis:

> Let us estimate the complexity of this algorithm. Immediately note
> that the case $n<k$ is analyzed by the old solution, which will work in
> this case for $O(k)$. Now consider the algorithm itself. In fact, after
> every iteration, instead of n numbers, we are left with $n(1−\frac 1k)$
> numbers, so the total number of iterations $x$
>
> of the algorithm can be found roughly from the following equation:
>
> $n(1−\frac 1k)x=1$,
>
> on taking logarithm on both sides, we obtain:
>
> $ln(n)+x.ln(1−\frac 1k)=0$, $x=\frac {−ln(n)} {ln(1−\frac1k)}$,
>
> using the decomposition of the logarithm into Taylor series, we obtain
> an approximate estimate:
>
> $x≈k.ln(n)$
>
> Thus, the complexity of the algorithm is actually $O(k.log(n))$ .

Comment: Please do not give link only answer. Links tend to rot. You might quote relevant parts or write answer yourself.